# Just a question about starting places for quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

So I'm 14 years old. I don't know if anyone would agree with what I'm doing but I'm really interested in learning quantum mechanics. The school I go to doesn't really have any sort of programs to help me learn things like this. Anyone have recommendations for books to start of from a base? I already have an understanding of basic physics and some other things about quantum physics. Is there anyone who can give me a book to start off with or anything like the mathematics to start? I plan on starting trig soon with a tutor so I can get closer to learning caucus earlier. So if anyone has any suggestions on what books to start with or where to start please tell me. Also if I do learn quantum mechanics can i apply that to be an astronaut?

Comment: Astronauts do no need any quantum mechanics. Before learning quantum mechanics, it's important to first fully master calculus, and also learn a lot about *linear algebra*. After that, you can start thinking about quantum physics---though, again, it will not be of any practical use for someone who wants to be an astronaut!

Comment: [Astronaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronaut) or [astronomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomer)? Because an astronomer *should* know quantum mechanics while an astronaut probably doesn't need to know it.

Comment: @max Unfortunately, this website is not an ideal place to ask such a question. If you are truly excited with QM (or physics in general) then I'd humbly recommend finishing calculus (say Thomas/Finney) and Mary L. Boas both. Then move on to any graduate level physics book (Feynman's lectures or Resnick-Halliday). Focus more on problem solving than on theory. Then your problem reduces to [this one](http://goo.gl/5F1ONM). Good luck!